# How to load new events into FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar 3.2. The problem is if I get the current events from calender and clear then add new ones to array. When I call

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'updateEvents',eventsList);
```

It does not work but throws error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined
    at Y (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at Bt.x [as updateEvents] (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
```

This is the code inside the button click handler

```
var items = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
items.splice(0, items.length);
items.push({
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2017-02-01'
            });
items.push({
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2017-02-07',
            end: '2017-02-10'
            });
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'updateEvents',items);
```

I have tried to use jquery version 2.2.4 and 3.1.1 but no luck

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/default.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='resources/css/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='resources/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='resources/js/moment-with-locales.min.js'></script>
<script src='resources/js/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

Comment: Why you need to splice items?

Comment: I remove the older events

Comment: Even if I remove it, I still get the error

Comment: try to add console.log(items); ...
It think `items` seems to be undefined.

Comment: They are not undefined

Comment: Array[2]
0
:
Object
1
:
Object -> That is the LOG

Comment: have you tried this, $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent',items);

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
    at normalizeEventTimes (fullcalendar.js:12633)
    at normalizeEventDates (fullcalendar.js:12613)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_rendering/renderEvent/

```
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar( /* option */);
 var items = [
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2017-02-01'
    }, {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2017-02-07',
        end: '2017-02-10'
    }
];
for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', items[i]);
}
```

**renderEvent** : Renders a new event on the calendar.

**Note**: event must be an Event Object with a title and start at the very least.

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/radonirinamaminiaina/yanjkad5/1/)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: event.start.clone is not a function
    at filterEventsWithinRange (fullcalendar.js:11868)